# Samsung Galaxy S 2 - Recovery mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, updates, external-sd, recovery-mode

I am trying to install an application to my Galaxy S 2 using the "apply update from sdcard" option from the recovery mode (the script in the update.zip is written to do that). The problem I am facing is that when I choose that option, I can't see my external sdcard (where update.zip resides).
Anyone can help with that please ??

Answer (score 1):

Take it off your external card and put it on the internal SD storage which is located at `/sdcard`.  Confusing, I know, but that's how Samsung has decided to do things.